# iOS difference between AppDelegate and ViewController class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

How do I know what code goes in the AppDelegate class and what code goes in the ViewController class. Both classes have a similar method of `viewDidLoad` in `UIViewController` and `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` in `UIApplicationDelegate`. I guess `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` would be called first and that's where you'd create your view. But could someone please explain what general code goes in each of those classes?

Comment: I strongly suspect a good iOS dev book. Best $30 you'll ever spend. And if you're in a big city, your library might have one. There is way more to this topic than your question covers.

Comment: There is nothing similar about `UIApplicationDelete applicationDidFinishLaunching` and `UIViewController viewDidLoad` other than both being methods in Cocoa-touch classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put it simply, the App Delegate is *special/different* in the sense that it gets application methods such as `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, or `applicationWillTerminate`. You want to use it for entire app setup or for preparation to terminate your app i.e. saving objects that need to be reused, clearing unnecessary objects, etc, vs just putting everything in there instead of the correlating view controller. It appears you confused `viewDidLoad` and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. `viewDidLoad` gets called when the view controller loads for the first time, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` gets called when the whole application is done loading.

Answer (score 2):

AppDelegate is used for the whole app, you can use it to manage the app life cycle, on the other hand, ViewController is used for a single view. you can use it to manage life cycle of a view. One app can have multiple views. but only one AppDelegate.