# Mac OS Xcode Swift 2.2 problems to control drag labels and buttons to the appdelegate.swift file

Tags: swift, macos, xcode7

I am new to swift programming for Mac apps.
I created a new project and created buttons and labels which I could "control drag" to the Viewcontroller.swift file but not to the Appdelegate.swift file.

Most youtube examples are for IOS and the ones for OS typically show folks making control-drag links to the Appdelegate.swift file.

I appreciate any help to allow me to make the control-drag function work from the storyboard to my appdelegate.swift file work..... Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

When creating IOS app the AppDelegate typically handles the loading of the model and custom controllers.

To access a custom controller from a ViewController, You can set an instance of the custom controller as a property of the ApplicationDelegare and use the sharedApplication method of UIApplication class to access the property.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454297/ios-difference-between-appdelegate-and-viewcontroller-class) will help you to understand more about what code goes in to Appdelegate.swift

Comment: Thank you for your post. I love to just work in the ViewController only. Do you know how the correct swift commands which work in the ViewController  to first load an image from a url and second load it in an ImageView. Thx.

Comment: I have answered your question which you have posted. In order to help you with another question I would suggest you to ask new one. You can mark this answer as right answer if my answer addressed your question. Thank you. @FJC

Answer (score 1):

The app delegate is used to control major "settings" and functions in the app. It is not usually used for small class items such as buttons. You should be able to do everything you need with just a view controller. If you have any more questions or would like to explain what you need to be able to do, ask here.